# Feature / bundle list for JPA [2.1] for Karaf

Tags: java, jpa, karaf

I'm trying to migrate project from Eclipse OSGi runtime environment to Karaf, and I prepare install script for depenendecies. It is quite a hard way, for example, transaction API requires javax.enterprise.cdi-api, and this requires

```
javax.el,version=3.0.0 from javax.el-api (6)
javax.inject,version=1.0.0 from com.eclipsesource.jaxrs.jersey-all (59)
javax.interceptor,version=1.2.0 from javax.interceptor-api (48)
```

For sure, I'm not the first and last person to go that way. Are there any ready features / bundle lists / install scripts which I could use for the process? And how / where to search for them?

Searching for "JPA 2.1 feature for Karaf" returns me the list of posts with problems people have building their feature list... no ready solutions...

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on `Apache ServiceMix 7.0.0` and I have a `JPA 2.3.0` feature which is available.

**Features list**

```
karaf@root>feature:list | grep jpa
deltaspike-jpa                          | 1.2.1            |          | Uninstalled | org.ops4j.pax.cdi-0.12.0    | Apache Deltaspike jpa support
camel-jpa                               | 2.16.4           |          | Uninstalled | camel-2.16.4                |
jpa                                     | 1.0.4            |          | Uninstalled | enterprise-4.0.8            | OSGi Persistence Container
jpa                                     | 2.3.0            | x        | Started     | enterprise-4.0.8            | OSGi Persistence Container
openjpa                                 | 2.2.2            |          | Uninstalled | enterprise-4.0.8            | Apache OpenJPA 2.2.x persistence engine support
openjpa                                 | 2.3.0            |          | Uninstalled | enterprise-4.0.8            | Apache OpenJPA 2.3.x persistence engine support
openjpa                                 | 2.4.1            |          | Uninstalled | enterprise-4.0.8            | Apache OpenJPA 2.4.x persistence engine support
deltaspike-jpa                          | 1.3.0            |          | Uninstalled | org.ops4j.pax.cdi-1.0.0.RC1 | Apache Deltaspike jpa support
drools6-jpa                             | 6.2.0.Final      |          | Uninstalled | servicemix-kie-7.0.0        | Drools 6 JPA support
```

The `JPA 2.3.0` is coming from `enterprise-4.0.8` features repository with URL `mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.0.8/xml/features`

**Repository list**

```
karaf@root>feature:repo-list
Repository                  | URL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.ops4j.pax.cdi-0.12.0    | mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/0.12.0/xml/features
jclouds-1.9.1               | mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/1.9.1/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.jdbc-0.9.0    | mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/0.9.0/xml/features
camel-2.16.4                | mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.16.4/xml/features
activemq-core-5.14.3        | mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.14.3/xml/features-core
org.ops4j.pax.web-4.3.0     | mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-features/4.3.0/xml/features
enterprise-4.0.8            | mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.0.8/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.cdi-1.0.0.RC1 | mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.0.0.RC1/xml/features
framework-4.0.8             | mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.0.8/xml/features
standard-4.0.8              | mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.0.8/xml/features
cxf-3.1.5                   | mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.5/xml/features
activemq-5.14.3             | mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.14.3/xml/features
servicemix-kie-7.0.0        | mvn:org.apache.servicemix.features/servicemix-kie/7.0.0/xml/features
spring-4.0.8                | mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.0.8/xml/features
servicemix-features-7.0.0   | mvn:org.apache.servicemix.features/servicemix-features/7.0.0/xml/features
servicemix-examples-7.0.0   | mvn:org.apache.servicemix.features/servicemix-examples/7.0.0/xml/features
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: Right way. I'm a bit further. Persistence unit still doesn't start.

Comment: Do you have any exception ?

Comment: diag shows problem with dependencies:
Missing dependencies:
(&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0))

Comment: Can you try to install `transaction` feature if you have it ?

Comment: Yeah, now I have further errors. Missing dependencies:
(&(osgi.unit.name=officialUnit)(objectClass=org.apache.aries.jpa.template.JpaTemplate))
Haven't I installed JPA? I've used jpa/2.5.0 - manual added feature from maven

Comment: If you didn't install JPA yet, you have to install it.